# OBIEE 11g - Manage Catalog Group (historic data)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee

I have been using OBIEE 11g for a long time and during that time I have deleted or edited many groups. Is there any .xml file or table in the database that keeps track of this historical data.

How can I learn, who created or edited a particular group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have actually backed up your catalog - or at least the /system folders then there is absolutely no way.

That's one reason why Oracle got rid of catalog groups altogehter and dropped them from the product

Comment: Well, am I able to get **current** data (who created the **group**, who added or removed which member, etc.) about catalog groups from any file such as .xml or .log (not historical)?

Comment: That's something that's not logged by default. You'd have to use custom logging for your OBIPS